# 16-bit obj files VC++

Tags: visual-c++, compilation, bootloader, 16-bit, object-files

How do I compile my VC++ project to a 16-bit flat object file for use in my bootloader I am working on?

To my understanding, an object file is technically already "flat" and the linker turns it into the destination executable format. What I want it to be able to obtain that object file and pass that and my assembly code (in obj format) through the linker to create a flat bootloader.

The [guide][1] is not very specific on where the files are located and just says that you use `cl.exe`, `link.exe`, and `ml.exe` (MASM).

The guide uses MASM, but I know how to output object files with NASM. My main problem is the VC++ thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 16-bit compiler from Microsoft was VC++ 1.52c. It's ancient, and probably not available any more. Even if it was, chances are pretty good that it wouldn't compile any recent code. Just to name a few of its most obvious shortcomings, it had no support for templates, exception handling, or namespaces at all.

I believe most people working on things like that any more use [Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) (which isn't exactly up to date either, but still better than VC++ 1.52c).

Comment: is watcom only available as installer? I would like to distribute it with my SVN code to make compilation easier...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: It's available as source code. From there packaging as you see fit is mostly a question of how ambitious you feel.

Comment: and does it output object files at all?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Yes, it produces object files (16-bit OMF, if memory serves). I don't remember for sure whether it's written in C++ or C (probably rather C-ish C++ by current standards); unless I'm badly mistaken, it's self-compiling.